# useing facebook php sdk fb-callback.php show empty

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

`php version : 5.6`

SDK： https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk

when clicking FB login button then call the `fb-callback.php`, it is an error , so I did some debugging, but I'm still confused, anyone can help? what is the next step to debugging?

[image]

fb-callback.php segment

[image]

php sdk code segment like below

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Comment: please edit your post, remove image screenshots and replace them with code snippets (plain text format).

Comment: `php version : 5.6` - IMHO not much point in continuing, as long as you did not update to at least a current version of the 7 branch. 5.6. is _massively_ outdated and hasn't even received any security fixes any more for ages now. That is not a good basis to start implementing something as critical & sensitive as a login functionality on.